# Modern tools for Java deployment

Tags: java, deployment

I'm trying to find deployment tools for Java and have come across a few which seem outdated (I see the latest time stamps from 2010 or 2009) like ControlTier, Smartfog.

I've been out of the loop on Java for a while but now need to deploy Java code to production. it is not within in a container, so basically I need pretty simple tasks such as compile, jar it up, sftp it to server, restart process. Something like capistrano for the ruby world. Are there  any equivalent solutions for Java? I know I could use cap for Java as well, but I figured I'd ask in case there are more Java-centric options.

Comment: It depends on how long you were out of loop for but check out Maven or ANT. Just google them . If you are after Continuous Integration, then while you were away Hudson killed Cruise Control and was then overthrown by Jenkins.

Comment: Try [Maestro](http://www.maestrodev.com/deploy).

Comment: well TeamCity is also an option for continuous integration.

Comment: Maven can do just about anything but you need to conform to its world.  Investigate - learn - do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a server-based application [kwateeSDCM](http://sdcm.kwatee.net) can take care of automating the deployment.

Answer (score 3):

[LiveRebel](http://liverebel.com) is a suitable tool for this task